# Matplotlib Complete Failure

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, package

Matplotlib is failing to work due to an error. Although it has a clear troubleshooting comment when it happens, I still don't understand this at all. It's worked before, this problem is after a reinstallation. I am running Linux (Ubuntu).

This problem arises when I install matplotlib through 'conda install matplotlib' (after installing conda of course) or using pip:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

When trying to run a simple program to test matplotlib, lets just say:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 3])
 plt.show()
```

Everything outside of the terminal freezes and nothing happens. If I tab out of the terminal and back in, it says:

```
import-im6.q16: unable to read X window image `': Resource temporarily unavailable @       error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/4977.
import-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PS' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/421.
```

What gives? I don't even know what I would have to grant access to in order for this to work.

Comment: How are you running this? Within some Python environment, or directly from the terminal?